# I want to run a specific drone pipeline in series

Tags: drone.io

I have a drone.yml running 3 pipelines on my github repo.  One for pullrequests that get run as soon as some one submits a pull request, a pipeline for releases that makes docker containers and outputs a docker-compose, and now I'm making a pipeline that runs integration tests after a merge into master.

One of the steps is that it updates a test server, which is making the task challenging.  Is there a way to force this specific drone pipeline to only run if there isn't any other of this pipeline running?

Answer (score 1):

You can used `depends_on` to force the order of the pipelines execution.

[Pipeline: Graph Execution](https://docs.drone.io/pipeline/configuration/#graph-execution)